# how to create header in excel from a python dictionary keys

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, header

I am trying to take a dictionary in python and place it into an excel worksheet where the keys are displayed in the header section of the sheet and the values are in to columns.  I am close I am just missing something small and cannot figure it out here is my code. Caution I use way to many imports

```
import os
import re
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string
import xlsxwriter
import pprint
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.copier import WorksheetCopy


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('dicExcel.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

d = {'a':['Alpha','Bata','Gamma'], 'b':['1','2','3'], 'c':['1.0','2.0','3.0']}
row = 0
col = 1

for key in d.keys():
row += 1
worksheet.write(row, col, key)
for item in d[key]:
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, item)
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('dicExcel.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

d = {'a':['Alpha','Bata','Gamma'], 'b':['1','2','3'], 'c':['1.0','2.0','3.0']}
row = 0
col = 0

for key in d.keys():
    row = 0
    worksheet.write(row, col, key)
    row += 1
    for item in d[key]:
        worksheet.write(row, col, item)
        row += 1
    col += 1

workbook.close()
```

This puts the data in this format:

```
a       c      b
Alpha   1.0    1
Bata    2.0    2
Gamma   3.0    3
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Exactly and thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) package, you won't need too many imports.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'a':['Alpha','Bata','Gamma'], 'b':['1','2','3'], 'c':['1.0','2.0','3.0']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

df will look like this:

```
       a  b    c
0  Alpha  1  1.0
1   Bata  2  2.0
2  Gamma  3  3.0
```

To write the DataFrame back in to an Excel file:

```
df.to_excel("Path to write Excel File + File Name")
```